# Find all month names between two given date in java

Tags: java

I need All month/Year names between two given date.I need this out put only on java.

Example :

```
Input Date:

    date 1- 20/12/2011 
    date 2- 22/08/2012

Now ,my expected result should be :- 

        Dec/2011
        Jan/2012
        Feb/2012
        Mar/2012
        Apr/2012
        May/2012
        Jun/2012
        Jul/2012
        Aug/2012
```

Could anybody help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have tried, but it only works if both given date with in a same year. Like 20/01/2012 to 23/05/2012.

Comment: The question was **what** have you tried - show us your code.

Comment: No need to use Joda-Time library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Joda-Time (since not specified, I *assume* you could at least have a look at what joda time is):

```
 LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate("2011-12-12");
 LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate("2012-11-11"); 
 while(date1.isBefore(date2)){
     System.out.println(date1.toString("MMM/yyyy"));
     date1 = date1.plus(Period.months(1));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you mate.I knew Joda-Time.But, my first priority is to do this without any third party use. Let me try with my own java code, if failure then , i will use Joda-Time.

Comment: @JDeveloper no problem! Eventually you will probably use only Joda-Time because it's superior to the standard libraries. There were a high number of votes to include Joda in JDK 7, but it did not happen. :( ThankYou==upvote on SO :)

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use [the Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and iterate from one date to the other one by adding a month at each iteration `using myCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`.

The Calendar class takes care of avoiding overflows and updating the other fields (here the year) for you.

Comment: Will you please provide the code.It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: I'm reluctant to write myself the complete code at this looks too much like a homework or online interview problem. And that would make the question/answer more specific than needed. Can you precise what you find hard from there ?

Comment: I think you should work it out.  It's not that hard. And your name is JDeveloper!

Comment: You are right @Dan Matthews-Grout.I am trying before 1 hour but, not solved.So, i posted this for Java Master's support.

Comment: Give me a minute to start my vm

Comment: Read the javadoc I linked too. Find how to initialize your myCalendar instance from the first date. Write your loop (see how to test the calendar isn't past the other date). Print results during iteration.

Comment: Oh, sure. I am trying here. You please try.

Comment: @JDeveloper the good practice on SO is to not write the complete or exact solution in such a case but give hints. We don't want SO to be a "Do my homework" site. I'm sure you can write it from the walkthrough I gave.

Comment: Compromise here that it isn't exactly what he wants but should so the methodology.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

## `java.time.YearMonth`

While the other answers were good answers when written, they are now outdated. Since Java 8 introduced the `YearMonth` class, this task has been greatly simplified:

```
    String date1 = "20/12/2011";
    String date2 = "22/08/2012";

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ROOT);
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM/uuuu", Locale.ROOT);
    YearMonth endMonth = YearMonth.parse(date2, dateFormatter);
    for (YearMonth month = YearMonth.parse(date1, dateFormatter);
            ! month.isAfter(endMonth);
            month = month.plusMonths(1)) {
        System.out.println(month.format(monthFormatter));
    }
```

This prints:

```
Dec/2011
Jan/2012
Feb/2012
Mar/2012
Apr/2012
May/2012
Jun/2012
Jul/2012
Aug/2012
```

Please supply an appropriate locale for the second call to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` to get the month names in your language. And the first call too to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4):

Per conversation above.  Use Calendar and the add method.

I've not tested this but it's about there:

```
public static List<Date> datesBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    List<Date> ret = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d1);
    while (c.getTimeInMillis()<d2.getTime()) {
        c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        ret.add(c.getTime());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I really don't think you should give the complete solution to a homework question.

Comment: It's not - he still needs to deal with String input and output ;) He asked for a code example to walk through. Personally I find that helpful as I can work backwards to see how it was achieved. Taking a puritan stance on "no complete" answers is a bit counter-productive to the aims of the site.  Plus I've not tested it, so it could have (probably not) bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(your_date_object);
 cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

So suppose you have these two date. And you can compare it easily by iterating an while loop till fromDate is before toDate.

```
Date fromDate= new Date("1/4/2016");
Date toDate = new Date("31/12/2016");

int i=0;
while(fromDate.before(toDate)){
    i=i+1;
    fromDate.setMonth(i);
    System.out.println(fromDate);
}
```

You can add date in list or do whatever do want to do!!!

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` and such.

### `LocalDate`

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate startLocalDate = LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.DECEMBER , 20 ) ;  
LocalDate stopLocalDate = LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.AUGUST , 2 ) ;
```

### `YearMonth`

When interested only in the year and month, use the class `YearMonth`.

```
YearMonth start = YearMonth.from( startLocalDate) ;
YearMonth stop = YearMonth.from( stopLocalDate ) ;
```

Loop.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM/uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
int initialCapacity = start.until( stop , ChronoUnit.MONTHS ) ;
List< YearMonth > yearMonths = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity ) ;
YearMonth ym = start ;
while ( ym.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    System.out.println( ym.format( f ) ) ;  // Output your desired text.
    yearMonths.add( ym ) ;
    ym = ym.plusMonths( 1 ) ;  // Increment to set up next loop.
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).